# Writing to CakePHP custom log file when in production mode

Tags: cakephp, logging, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to ensure that CakePHP writes to a custom log file when my app is in production mode.

I'm writing to the log using the log method:-

```
$this->log($url, 'payment');
```

This work's fine when I'm in a development mode, but when I switch to production mode it no longer writes to the file (which is what I want it to do).

I've tried configuring a file logging option in bootstrap.php which is partially fixing the issue:-

```
CakeLog::levels(array('payment'));
CakeLog::config('payment', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('payment'),
    'file' => 'payment',
));
```

This now writes to the log file in production mode, but it is also writing other errors to my payment.log which I don't want in there.

I've tried reading through the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html) but either it doesn't explain how to achieve this or I am misunderstanding it.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for any help.

Comment: No. I was never able to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6):

I think this may help you:

Call:

```
CakeLog::write('info', 'log msg', array('payments'));
```

Bootstrap:

```
CakeLog::config('payments', array(
    'engine' => 'FileLog',
    'types' => array('info'),
    'scopes' => array('payments')
));
```

As documentation describes, scopes are available in 2.2: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#logging-scopes

You tagged the question with cakephp 2.1. Maybe you just need to upgrade: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-2-migration-guide.html

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the luxury of upgrading Cake for this project. I was hoping this is something that is doable in CakePHP 2.1.